# What does Oracle call a SID?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I need to connect to a remote Oracle database using SQL Developer. I tried to create a new connection and I would like to know what exactly is A `SID`? Is it a parameter I need to check in my Oracle database?

Comment: I know this isn't your question, but it might help you get connected more quickly. If someone else is responsible for the database, ask them about TNS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SID` (System ID) is the name of the database you are connecting to. A server can host multiple databases, so you need to specify the name.

See also: http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/ORACLE_SID

You can get it like this, once you're connected, but given the situation, that might not be very helpful. :D

```
select sys_context('userenv', 'instance_name') from dual
```

Answer (score 1):

SID = Instance name as defined at instance creation on the database server.

On the database server, check the tnsnames.ora file:

SERVICE_NAME=
or
SID=

Comment: Correct. Only difference is SERVICE_NAME references a database in a RAC environment.

Comment: Not necessarily, as we use SERVICE_NAME across the board for standalone single instance and RAC.